# What rights do EU travellers have when they miss a flight due to it leaving early?

Tags: eu, passenger-rights

I know there are some pretty traveller-friendly passenger rights in the EU for those people whose flights are delayed, cancelled, bumped or downgraded, but what rights do travellers have if they miss a flight because the gates closed 20 minutes *earlier* than stated on the ticket?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Were you checked in to the flight? Which airline was involved? Generally, an airline can require you to be at the gate in advance of the departure time.

Comment: Of possible related interest: *[Why would an aircraft take off earlier than the planned departure time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112965)* and *[Is “departure time” when the plane leaves the gate or when it takes off?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107373/)*

Comment: Time on ticket is not much relevant, if an airlines changed time at least one week before. Do you mean ticket or boarding card? What was the times at airports?

Comment: Can you clarify what the scheduled departure time was, and what was the actual departure time and/or gate closing time? It is normal for the date to close before the departure time, and 20 minutes is pretty standard.

Comment: It entirely depends what's stated on the *ticket* - typically it's the departure time.  The *boarding pass* may show the gate closure time in addition.  The times by which you need to present yourself at various points (checkin, baggage drop, security, the gate) are normally part of the conditions of carriage of your ticket, and usually stated as x minutes or hours before departure. So what are you actually referring to - ticket or boarding pass - and what does it actually say on it?

Comment: Most of the time there are warnings written about being at the gate some time before official departure.